# Dns reversezone not working

Tags: dns, reverse-dns

dig PTR  192.168.1.41 is not working for me

But I am getting the answer for the forward zone I checked the configuration files .there are no errors.

Comment: 1) "is not working" is not really useful. What happens exactly? and 2) always specify which nameserver you query when using `dig` especially since `192.168.1.0/24` is certainly not delegated to you worldwide

Answer (score 0):

`dig PTR 192.168.1.41` checks for the PTR record of the IP, which it has not, because the PTR is for the reverse zone (it's a different thing). To check the PTR of a reverse zone use proper hostname from the reverse zone. In your case if the PTR record is properly configured the command is:

`dig PTR 41.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa`

Comment: Or far simpler: `dig -x 192.168.1.41`

Comment: dig PTR 41.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa tried but not digging.